# How to install IIS on Widows XP. Got local admin rights, but don't have "install compoments" tab in Add/Remove programms

Tags: windows-xp, iis, iis-6

I have Windows XP CD, have a local admin rights on my PC. How do I install IIS on my machine, if the "Install Windows compoments" tab does not show up when I bring up "Add or Remove Programm" window.

Comment: Fiddling with IIS on XP is something I expect you're going to get a lot more input on from SU users.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XP Home, then this is the problem.  IIS does not come with XP Home.
A workaround can be found here: adamv.com/dev/articles/iis-on-xp-home/ although it is quite technical and requires a spare Windows 2000 installation CD <- even I don't carry one of these around with me anymore.

You could try running a different web server such as Cassini which can host basic ASP pages.
http://ultidev.com/products/Cassini/ (it is free.)

If XP Professional, a few things to try:

Can you try launching 'Install Windows Components' using another method:
Click Start | Click Run | Type: %windir%\system32\sysocmgr.exe and click OK.

Alternatively, you should be able to download the latest version of IIS (7.0) directly from the Microsoft website.  Here is the link for you: microsoft dot com/Web/platform/server dot aspx (sorry, would only let me post one URL!)

Failing all of this, try:
Click Start | Click Run | Type: sfc /scannow
Wait for the black box to disappear.  You may need to pop in your Windows XP CD for the tool to replace any broken system files which might be preventing 'Install Windows Components' from opening.  Cancel out of the Install Windows screen if it auomatically appears) and then restart.  This may fix the initial problem and then allow you to install how you were trying to install.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am using XP Pro SP2

Answer (score 0):

The Install Windows Components window can also be launched by going to Start > Run and typing

```
control appwiz.cpl,,2
```